# Trying to download file to directory and android gives StrictModeViolation: policy=79 violation=1

Tags: android

Background: I come across this from this book "The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development" 
Source code location: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Internet/Download

I am trying to build a function to perform background download and this example seems to show what I need to learn.   However, just by starting to download, I get the following error:

```
02-19 23:09:28.572    1563-1563/com.commonsware.android.downmgr E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.commonsware.android.downmgr, PID: 1563
    android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeViolation: policy=79 violation=1
            at android.os.StrictMode.executeDeathPenalty(StrictMode.java:1379)
            at android.os.StrictMode.access$1300(StrictMode.java:118)
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.handleViolation(StrictMode.java:1372)
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.handleViolationWithTimingAttempt(StrictMode.java:1199)
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.startHandlingViolationException(StrictMode.java:1169)
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onWriteToDisk(StrictMode.java:1112)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.mkdir(BlockGuardOs.java:172)
            at java.io.File.mkdirErrno(File.java:874)
            at java.io.File.mkdirs(File.java:898)
            at java.io.File.mkdirs(File.java:892)
            at com.commonsware.android.downmgr.DownloadFragment.startDownload(DownloadFragment.java:94)
```

The manifest is set to have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

The line that it bomb out is
    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).mkdirs();

If I remove that line, the next line that it bombs out is

req.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                                   | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
       .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
       .setTitle("Demo")
       .setDescription("Something useful. No, really.")
       .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                                          "test.mp4");

This is the code that I am trying to get download working

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse("http://commonsware.com/misc/test.mp4");

Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
           .mkdirs();

DownloadManager.Request req=new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

req.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                               | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
   .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
   .setTitle("Demo")
   .setDescription("Something useful. No, really.")
   .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                                      "test.mp4");

  StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
          .detectDiskReads()
          .detectDiskWrites()
          .detectNetwork()
          .penaltyLog()
          .penaltyDeath()
          .build());
lastDownload=mgr.enqueue(req);

v.setEnabled(false);
query.setEnabled(true);
```

Please let me know what does that policy+violation mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disk write/read operations are potentially long and theoretically can cause ANR error. StrictMode detects such operations and throw exception. You specify to observe it in StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder:

> .detectDiskReads() .detectDiskWrites()

To remove this exception you can perform disk operations in another thread or turn off StrictMode.

Answer (score 1):

At the end, this is what I did, I wrap the problem code in a background task, and have whoever that was launching the following code. do

```
AddStringTask task=new AddStringTask();
task.execute();
```

This is the AsyncTask

```
class AddStringTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {

        Uri uri= Uri.parse("http://commonsware.com/misc/test.mp4");

        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PODCASTS)
                .mkdirs();

        DownloadManager.Request req=new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

        req.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
                .setTitle("Demo")
                .setDescription("Something useful. No, really.")
                .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
                        "test.mp4");

        lastDownload=mgr.enqueue(req);

        return(null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... item) {
        if (!isCancelled()) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        if (!isCancelled()) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }


    }
}
```